# JMESPath query on Azure cloud storage returning blank

Tags: azure, jmespath

I can explore on Azure explorer and see the blob exists but when I run the query, it is returning blank. Can anyone help with the issue? It just keeps on running when I remove the limit on number of Results.

```
numResults=4000
az storage blob list \
       --account-name $account_name \
       --account-key $key \
       --show-next-marker \
       --container-name $container_name \
       --query "[].name | [?((ends_with(@, 'bam')) && (contains(@, '886678')))]"
```

Here is the snapshot of Azure explorer
[image]

Comment: I have created a couple of sample files in my storage account with above shared naming notation and by using the shared cmdlet able to pull the particular file name which ends with ( bam only) and below the attached screenshot for your reference.

https://i.imgur.com/N7Sd63c.png

Comment: query works because I do get results sometimes. After a detailed investigation, I figured my query works until a certain point. After that query doesn't produce any result and Azure CLI just kills the query.
As a workaround, I wrote a script that searches for 1000 files at a time and generate nextMarker for the subsequent query. I run it in a loop until nextMarker is empty but after an hour of run, even though nextMarker is not NULL, Azure just kills my query. I tried restarting with the same nextMarker but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.